# How to hide unit when the quantity is empty on the table?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table that looks a following:

[image]

As you can see on the picture, 0 quantity is marked with red border.
I tried as following

```
const sValuePath = "{Objects>" + oProp.NameChar + "}";
return new sap.m.ObjectNumber({
    number: sValuePath,
    unit: oProp.UnitTExt,
    visible: "{= ${sValuePath} > 0}"
});
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebastian Mahr commented, you are ending up with double curly braces:

Already has curly braces:

```
const sValuePath = "{Objects>" + oProp.NameChar + "}";
```

More curly braces:

```
visible: "{= ${sValuePath} > 0}"
```

Starting with your original code:

```
const sValuePath = "{Objects>" + oProp.NameChar + "}";
return new sap.m.ObjectNumber({
    number: sValuePath,
    unit: oProp.UnitTExt,
    visible: "{= ${sValuePath} > 0}"
});
```

you need to add string concatenation AND remove the extra curly braces, so you will end up with:

```
const sValuePath = "{Objects>" + oProp.NameChar + "}";
return new sap.m.ObjectNumber({
    number: sValuePath,
    unit: oProp.UnitTExt,
    visible: "{= $"+ sValuePath + " > 0}"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use expression binding in XML view where your cell is defined for that column

Something Like IDK depends what you use, see my example below

```
<Text text="{=$(quantity) === '' ? '' : $(quantity) + '' + $(unit)}" />
```

Hope, this helps

Answer (score 0):

you are not concatinating the string in the visibiliry property and even if you would you en up with double `{}`

try somthing like :

```
const sValuePath = "Objects>" + oProp.NameChar;
return new sap.m.ObjectNumber({
    number: "{"+sValuePath+"}",
    unit: oProp.Currency,
    visible: "{= ${"+sValuePath+"} > 0}"
});
```

Comment: I tried `"{= ${"+sValuePath+"} > 0}"` but the unit is still showing.